# Converting 'bs4.element.NavigableString' to json

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I need to convert a  `bs4.element.NavigableString` (which is from beautiful soup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) into a json string.

I am using beautiful soup to scrape, and I am having what *looks* like a json object returned, which looks like the following (without the pretty formatting):

```
my_object = {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I have tried to search `my_object` with the normal json methodology, but it does't work, as well as tried searching through it with beautiful soup's methodology. I have also searched for how to convert the `bs4.element.NavigableString` into a json.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the future, instead of describing what you tried to do and saying "it doesn't work", show us your code, and how it didn't work (the exception with traceback, or the expected and actual values, etc.). It's hard to guess what you mean by "search… with the normal json methodology".

Answer (score 1):

Well, that string isn't valid JSON. *Part of it* is valid JSON.

In particular, it's a line of JavaScript code that assigns a JavaScript literal that happens to be written as valid JSON to a `my_object` variable.

If you want to parse the JSON, you have to separate it out from the rest of the statement. For example:

```
s = '''my_object = {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}'''
jsvar, _, jsvalue = s.partition('=')
value = json.loads(jsvalue)
```