# Parse HTML and extract data from a tag's string (in JSON format)

Tags: python, json, html-parsing

From a Html file a tag was extracted

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=open("centrimo.html")
parsed_html=BeautifulSoup(html)
script_data=parsed_cen.script
```

Now from the string contained in the script tag I would like to extract the information in the variables "sequences", "neg_sequences", "seqs" and "nseqs".

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  //@JSON_VAR data
  var data = {
    "version": "5.3.3",
    "revision": "1667d7719daf2af1693cc039ba463bc4d2304d23",
    "release": "Sun Feb 7 15:39:52 2021 -0800",
    "program": "CentriMo",
    "options": {
      "cd": false,
      "neg_sequences": true,
      "noseq": false,
      "mcc": false
    },
    "seqlen": 101,
    "tested": 435,
    "alphabet": {
      "name": "DNA",
      "like": "dna",
      "ncore": 4
    },
    "background": [0.2788, 0.2212, 0.2212, 0.2788],
    "sequences": [
      "AT1G04100.1_CDS", "AT1G05860.1_CDS", "AT1G13910.1_CDS",
      "AT1G21065.1_CDS", "AT1G26190.1_CDS", "AT1G32940.1_CDS",
      "AT1G50575.1_CDS", "AT1G55810.1_CDS", "AT1G66430.1_CDS",
      "AT1G71430.1_CDS", "AT1G77170.1_CDS", "AT1G78610.1_CDS",
      "AT2G02955.1_CDS", "AT2G16280.1_CDS", "AT2G17080.1_CDS",
      "AT2G19620.1_CDS", "AT2G19640.1_CDS", "AT2G30840.1_CDS",
      "AT2G39450.1_CDS", "AT2G41380.1_CDS", "AT2G42580.1_CDS",
      "AT3G01680.1_CDS", "AT3G05680.1_CDS", "AT3G20110.1_CDS",
      "AT3G20260.1_CDS", "AT3G21360.1_CDS", "AT3G23070.1_CDS",
      "AT3G23590.1_CDS", "AT3G46820.1_CDS", "AT3G48250.1_CDS",
      "AT3G61200.1_CDS", "AT4G08510.1_CDS", "AT4G15070.1_CDS",
      "AT4G24670.1_CDS", "AT4G25450.1_CDS", "AT4G28600.1_CDS",
      "AT4G31910.1_CDS", "AT4G34810.1_CDS", "AT4G35030.3_CDS",
      "AT4G37170.1_CDS", "AT4G38630.1_CDS", "AT4G39720.1_CDS",
      "AT5G07340.1_CDS", "AT5G12970.1_CDS", "AT5G13470.1_CDS",
      "AT5G18950.1_CDS", "AT5G22840.1_CDS", "AT5G25590.1_CDS",
      "AT5G27395.1_CDS", "AT5G53370.1_CDS", "AT5G63610.1_CDS",
      "AT5G64830.1_CDS", "AT5G64900.1_CDS", "AT5G67620.1_CDS"
    ],
    "neg_sequences": [
      "AT1G01600.1_CDS", "AT2G32480.1_CDS", "AT2G41740.1_CDS",
      "AT3G19490.1_CDS", "AT3G24030.1_CDS", "AT3G25580.1_CDS",
      "AT3G48330.1_CDS", "AT3G59220.1_CDS", "AT4G13340.1_CDS",
      "AT4G33590.1_CDS", "AT5G03080.1_CDS", "AT5G23700.1_CDS",
      "AT5G41010.1_CDS"
    ],
    "motifs": [
      {
        "db": 2,
        "id": "ath-miR419",
        "alt": "MIMAT0001327",
        "consensus": "CAACATCCTCAGCATTCATAA",
        "len": 21,
        "motif_evalue": "0.0e+000",
        "motif_nsites": 20,
        "n_tested": 40,
        "score_threshold": 5,
        "url": "http://www.mirbase.org/cgi-bin/mature.pl?mature_acc=MIMAT0001327",
        "pwm": [
          [0.164036, 0.479478, 0.163749, 0.192738],  
          [0.479764, 0.163749, 0.192452, 0.164036]
        ],
        "total_sites": 10,
        "sites": [
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        ],
        "neg_total_sites": 2,
        "neg_sites": [
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        ],
        "seqs": [0, 1, 13, 15, 16, 23, 27, 36, 44, 48],
        "neg_seqs": [3, 10],
        "peaks": [
          {
            "center": 0,
            "fisher_log_adj_pvalue": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
</script>
```

I tried to convert the object into a json type object but I got the following error,

```
import json
j_script = json.loads(script_data.string)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 7 (char 7)
```

Thanks in advance

PS. an example of a complete html file that I would like to parse can be found ([here](https://meme-suite.org/meme/doc/examples/centrimo_example_output_files/centrimo.html))

Edit: In the original post I mentioned that I got an indentation error. That happened after trying to manually edit the json object by removing all the white spaces, "\n" characters. Although I don't think it fundamentally changes the question, I apologize for the mistake

[UPDATE] I was able to adapt the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023346/converting-bs4-element-navigablestring-to-json) as follows

```
tmp=script_data.string.partition('=')
j_tmp=tmp[2].replace(";\n    ","")  
j_script=json.loads(j_tmp)
```

The second line is a bit clumsy (I couldn't adapt the answer in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368058/how-can-i-parse-javascript-variables-using-python)) but overall it does the trick. Now I'm trying to obtain the 'seqs' data which is contained in the "motifs" list.

Help with the second line in the code above will be much appreciated

Comment: It could be that it's including the assignment `var data =` and not just the object in the script_data string

Comment: My apologies, actually the error I got from the json.loads command was different and pointed to different lines in the input. Because the original input is longer and a bit more complex. I tried to manually edit (by removing tabs, newline characters and even \n characters) and then test the command. That is when I got the indentation error. Now I away from the computer but once I get back, I will properly edit the post

Comment: There is a way to get the target data, but the data I get from the page is different from the one in your question. For example, `"version": "5.3.3"` is `"version": "5.3.2"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best answer that I could come up with.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html=open("<HTML File>")
parsed_html=BeautifulSoup(html)
script_data=parsed_html.script
tmp=script_data.string.partition('=')
 
#Replace the last part of the tupple (tmp)
j_tmp=tmp[2].replace(";\n    ","")  
 
j_script=json.loads(j_tmp)
 
seq_id=j_script["sequences"]
 
#Loop over the dictionaries looking for "seqs"
for idict in j_script["motifs"]:
    if "seqs" in idict:
        dict_tmp=idict
      
seq_n=dict_tmp["seqs"]
```

The code still needs improvement but I think it can do the job now.